# How to get a custom property with Cognito Idp and the javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

With the AWS cognito SDK for javascript I'm using `cognitoUser.getUserAttributes()` to read user attributes but it does not return any custom attribute.

Same if I use the console with:

```
aws cognito-idp get-user --access-token Y
```

However when I'm using `admin-get-user` the custom attribute is returned properly

```
aws cognito-idp admin-get-user --user-pool-id X --username Y
```

Is it normal that the custom attribute is not returned with `cognitoUser.getUserAttributes()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve them with the getUserAttributes call. The custom attributes are prefixed by the word custom such as and they should be present in the list of attributes you have set:

```
custom:name_you_have_set
```

One thing you might want to check is in the console under the client you have created for the Javascript SDK to access the user pool is if you have marked the custom attribute as readable, you might not be able to retrieve it if it is not marked as readable.

Comment: Thanks, indeed read permission wasn't set for the custom attribute. I've created the app before creating the custom attribute, I guess that why it was not set a readable.